# PHP Closing With > key

Tags: php

I tried to test a mysql connection with an if statement. It looks like this

```
    <php
    $mysql_host = "mysql12.000webhost.com";
    $mysql_database = "a3860164_users";
    $mysql_user = "a3860164_admin";
    $mysql_password = "admin1";


    $conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT `email` FROM  `users` ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (strpos($row,$_POST[email]) !== false) {
    header( 'Location: /register.html?message=This email is already registered' ) ;
}
}
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (`data`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (NULL, $_POST[email], $_POST[password])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header( 'Location: /register.html?message=An error occured. Try again.' ) ;
} else {
    header( 'Location: /register.html?message=An error occured. Try again.' ) ;
}
</php>
```

The > key closes the php tag so the rest of my php code can't run. How can I fix this? This is on a 3rd party host.

Comment: I think you want to use: `if (!$conn) die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());` `mysql_*` API isn't OOP! Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: *"The > key closes the php ..."* What does that mean?

Comment: @Rizier123 Don't encourage him to use `mysql_*` functions. Looks like he already uses mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: @GergoErdosi I didn't read anything about `mysqli_*` in OP's question only about `mysql_*`

Comment: @Rizier123 Which part mentions `mysql_*` in OP's question?

Comment: Also please show us a few lines above this

Comment: The problem is with the opening tag, not with the closing tag. Change `<php` to `<?php`.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: I just now see, the closing tag is wrong too. Change `</php>` to `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","wrong_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
?>
```

Comment: We encourage answers containing code to be accompanied by a textual description of what was modified - it isn't clear otherwise.

Comment: Please provide context.